# Can not open Bootstrap Model popup

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4

I have an Bootstrap Popup control in my application.I can not open "Model popup" when I click on button.Please check my below code and advise where it is problem.I have taken this example code from below link

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/

```
 render() {


    return (
      <form>


<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>


<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</form>


    );
  }
}
```

Comment: can you please share jsfiddle link?

Comment: I tried your code and its work fine

Comment: please check updated code and advise how to solve this issue....

Comment: please help....

Answer (score 0):

As per bootstrap link you have shared Bootstrap Modal has dependency on jQuery.

```
So, By adding the following below CDN links in your index.html it will start working.

<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
/>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
></script>
<script
  src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
></script>

Thanks.
```

Comment: thanks for reply,but i would like to call bootstrap popup modal in react application.so what is the best way to call modal popup in react js ?? Is there any separate component available ??? please advise...